# Z-index below text but above background

Tags: html, css, z-index

I'm trying to get a div to show as a partial background below the inline content of is containing div but above the background of its container. If I set the z-index of just the partial background to -1 it appears behind the background. But if i set the containing divs z-index to 1 while the contained div's z-index is -1 it displays as desired.

Can someone explain to me why this is and if this is a reliable method or not?

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  height: 18px;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  background: #666;
  z-index: 1;
}

.partialbg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 80%;
  background: #0CC;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">Text here
  <div class="partialbg"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason this is occurring, is because there is a child and a parent. If you set a `z-index` on the parent, the child is going to be the same, since the `z-index` is stacked.

Thus, by setting a `z-index` of `1` on the parent, the child is now also `1`.

It is systematically impossible for the child to be behind the parent, as that doesn't make any sense. However, the text is a **sibling** of the **child**. By setting a `z-index` of `-1` on the child, there is essentially no effect between the child and the parent, however since the sibling is effected, the child now goes behind the sibling.

Comment: For me the explanation is that the siblings, the text and the `div class=partialbg` inherit the `z-index` of `1`. But putting a `z-index` of `-1` creates a RELATIVE `z-index`: one sibling is below the other one, even if they are both `1` (inherited from the parent)