# Is position: fixed z-index relative to its parent's z-index?

Tags: css, css-position, z-index

I have a fixed position element inside a relatively positioned element, as far as I'm concerned the `position: relative` element shouldn't have any effect on the `position: fixed` (fixed elements are positioned relative to the window, right?).

However, the fixed elements z-index seems to be inherited by it's parent, to the point where it's z-index can be no higher than its parent's z-index.

I hope I'm making sense? Below is a HTML example of what I'm talking about:

```css
.outer { 
    position: relative; 
    z-index: 2; 
}
.inner { 
    background: #fff; 
    left: 50px; 
    position: fixed; 
    top: 40px; 
    z-index: 1000000; 
}

.fade { 
    background: #555; 
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    opacity: 0.5; 
    position: fixed; 
    right: 0; 
    top: 0; 
    z-index: 3; 
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">testing testing</div>
</div>
<div class="fade"></div>
```

If you change the following:

```
.outer { position: relative; z-index: 4; }
```

Then the `.inner` element appears in front of the fade element.

I find this behaviour very peculiar... is there a way of working around this without moving the `.inner` div, or changing the CSS of the `.outer` div?

Fiddles of above code samples:

http://jsfiddle.net/n2Kq5/

http://jsfiddle.net/U8Jem/1/

Comment: Might be related to these answers I wrote a while back.. **[How to reverse the order of nested child elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454901/how-to-reverse-the-order-of-nested-child-elements/19455098#19455098)** and **[Z-index below text but above background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523136/z-index-below-text-but-above-background/19523501#19523501)** Pretty sure either one of them will help you.. it's not possible for the child element to have a higher `z-index` than the parent - as explained in my answers.

Comment: Do you mean [like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/n2Kq5/4/)?

Comment: @Zeaklous thanks, but that doesn't quite work how it needs too, see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lwj22/ The black bg/white text needs to appear behind the fade, whilst the white bg needs to appear in front of it, you're example means both appear in front of the modal.

Comment: And thanks @JoshC reading through them now, doesn't look like there's going to be an easy solution to this problem unfortunately :(

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In short, yes, an element with `position:fixed` is limited by its parent's z-index given the parent's `z-index` is defined.

Sad to inform you, but what you want is not currently possible. The only way you can get the effect you desire is to *change your HTML* or *remove the z-index* from `outer`.

**Changing HTML options**

The first option is to move `inner` outside of `outer`, which would look [**like this**](http://jsfiddle.net/n2Kq5/5/).

The second option for an HTML fix is to move `fade` inside of `outer` (using the same CSS even) - [**demo of that here**](http://jsfiddle.net/n2Kq5/6/).

A third option would be to put `fade` inside of `outer` and then also put `inner` inside of `fade`, but that requires you to use rgba colors and opacity - [**that demo is found here**](http://jsfiddle.net/n2Kq5/7/).

**Changing CSS options**

The closest thing you can get using the same HTML you have currently is to remove the z-index of `outer` - [**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lwj22/1/). You would think that you could simply increment each element's z-index by two, but that does not work due to the fact that children elements cannot have a higher z-index than their parents (if the parent's z-index is set).

---

### Explanation

If you think about it, `fade` and `outer` are on the same level. What you're trying to do is have `fade` remain on that same level but *also* have it be on the level above, which is impossible. It's like trying to be on two floors of a building at once, it can't be done.

Although what you need is not directly related to this article, Philip Walton created a great post on [z-indexes and the effect opacity has on them](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/), which could be useful to others looking at this question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (and the link, definitely going to read that soon!). I thought this might be the case, I still think it's not intuitive for a fixed element to inherit it's parents z-index (as for all intensive purposes it's relative to the window) but I guess if that's the way the spec is written I'll just have to deal with it